# React - Scoping issue with setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that will basically serve as a fully self-contained file being uploaded. For the time being, until I get the upload mechanism in place, I'm just using a timer to simulate a progress change. However, when it hits 100% and tries to send a message to its parent (via `statusChange`), I've got a scoping issue where `this` is referring to `window`. How can I fix this?

The actual error:

> Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.statusChange is not a function

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({progress: this.state.progress + 5});
      if (this.state.progress === 100) {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.props.statusChange({uploadComplete: true});
      }
    }, 1000);

    debugMode && console.info('[FileUpload] Began uploading %s',
      this.props.name);
  },
```

EDIT:
The problem seems to be in the passing of the callback. `this.props.statusChange` is indeed null the entire time.

Ahhh, damn! It was a scoping issue here. I'll highlight it below:

```
UploadQueue = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'UploadQueue',

  propTypes: {
    fileList: React.PropTypes.any.isRequired
  },

  statusChange(status) {
    debugMode && console.info('[UploadQueue] Status change! %o', status);
  },

  render() {
    let files = [];

    // Convert to a true array
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.fileList.length; ++i) {
      files = files.concat(this.props.fileList[i]);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {files.map(function (file) { // should be: {files.map(file => {
          return <FileUpload key={file.name}
                             name={file.name}
                             statusChange={this.statusChange} />
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Does your debug message print properly? Could you verify that the `this` directly inside `componentDidMount` is correct? The code seems fine to me.

Comment: Yep, the `console.info` prints just fine. The odd thing is, the `if (this.state.progress === 100)` check also works just fine. I don't get it.

Comment: Wait, so does the error actually include that preliminary underscore? As in `_this.props.statusChange`?

Comment: @HawkenRives I'm sure it comes from a transpiled source.

Comment: @ffxsam if you run a debugger and break inside the `setInterval` handler - does the `this.props` have anything in there at all?

Comment: Ok, for some reason, the `statusChange` prop is not getting passed properly for some reason.

Comment: @zerkms: Indeed. I was not thinking clearly there.

Comment: Got it! The issue was in another file. Post edited.

Comment: @ffxsam proper IDEs (webstorm/phpstorm) would highlight it

Comment: @zerkms Highlight what?

Comment: @ffxsam `this` that is likely to be used in a wrong way.

Comment: @zerkms I have WebStorm and it didn't warn me. Probably because I'm using JSX format, and their syntax detection there is not quite up to par just yet. Hopefully in WebStorm 11.

Comment: @ffxsam oh right, does not work for when used in JSX context, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`this` scoping issue was in the component that owns `FileUpload`. Fixed code below.

```
{files.map(file => {
  return <FileUpload key={file.name}
                     name={file.name}
                     statusChange={this.statusChange} />
})}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.timer = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState({progress: this.state.progress + 5});
    if (this.state.progress === 100) {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
      this.props.statusChange({uploadComplete: true});
    }
  }.bind(this), 1000);
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  debugMode && console.info('[FileUpload] Began uploading %s',
    this.props.name);
},
```

Comment: That has no effect.. it's redundant, because I'm already using the ES6 `=>` syntax.